# Using a function while keeping "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have  a function set up like this:

```
$('.color').each(function(){
    $(this).val('stuff');
});
```

As you can see, for each .color function, I'm setting the val of the selected .color item to "stuff".

However, I only want to set the value of `$this` when the mouse has clicked up.  For example:

```
$('.color').each(function(){
    $(window).mouseup(function(){
        $(this).val('stuff');
    });
});
```

However, this will change `this` to `window` instead of keeping the value at `.color` (or so I think unless I'm mistaken.)

How can I still use `$(this)` while keeping the same value as though it didn't have another function above it?

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle with HTML too?

Comment: Can I have a reason for all of the downvotes?

Comment: @AlexanderLozada I didn't downvote, but I think it is because this is a question that is asked once a day on SO.

Comment: I looked around, and I couldn't find anything - probably because this is probably a very bad way to go about doing anything at all.  Maybe I just answered my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood with `registering events` for elements with a common `class`. You don't need to iterate that, just use the following snippet.

Try,

```
$('.color').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).val('stuff');
});
```

I think you may looking for something like this,

```
$(window).mouseup(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('.color')){
      $(e.target).val('stuff');
    }
});
```

And finally, if you want to go in a wronger way, you can just correct your code by using cache variables, meaning cache the current object before event binding.

```
var cacheWinow= $(window);

$('.color').each(function(){
  var cacheThis = $(this);
  cacheWinow.mouseup(function(){
      cacheThis.val('stuff');
  });
};
```

Comment: you and the OP are missing a `.`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I simplified the code a bit when posting and I think I may need to keep the $('.color').each(function() in order to satisfy a jquery plugin I'm using.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy If you have to ask that then maybe the question should be closed.

Comment: ok, removed my **-1** because you've updated to a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Fortunately, I realized that the plugin I was using was causing such unnecessary workarounds that'd it'd be best just to look for another plugin - so It'll be a lot cleaner now.

Answer (score 1):

Then you would need a reference to the object you're talking about like this

```
$('.color').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(window).mouseup(function(){
        $this.val('stuff');
    });
});
```

Not advising on the use of the window part, but changing the whole thing does not answer your question.

You should use mouseup on the actual element not window

Another thing you should be doing is wrapping `window` **only** once like this

```
var $window = $(window);
$('.color').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $window.mouseup(function(){
        $this.val('stuff');
    });
});
```

If you don't you will be calling the `jQuery` constructor every single time you `mouseup` and that is **not** necessary

Comment: Looks like `each` event is not closed properly. The same stuff is in OP's code

Comment: @Pavlo if you see minor errors like that its fine to edit it out, you'll get reputation for it, I've done it now though

Comment: @JustDon't Sorry I did NOT see your answer here as I was too focused on Raj's answer.  But credit where credit due +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(window).mouseup(function(){
    $(".color").val('stuff');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cache `.color`. Like this:

```
$('.color').each(function () {
  var color = $(this);
  $(window).mouseup(function () {
      color.val('stuff');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to preserving `this`, or keeping the scope, you can also use `proxy()` or `bind()` etc. Example using `proxy()`:

#### »[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/47y7w/)«

Anonymous function:

```
$('.color').each(function(){
    $(window).mouseup(
        $.proxy(function(){ $(this).val('stuff') }, this)
        //                                            |
        //                                            +--- this is "this" of each
    )
});
```

Named function:

```
function other(str) {
    $(this).val(str);
//     |
//     +---- "this" (in this case) is "this" of each.
}

$('.other').each(function(){
    $(window).mouseup(
        $.proxy(other, this, 'other stuff')
    //                   |      |
    //                   |      +--- Arguments
    //                   +---------- this is "this" of each
    )
});
```

As to if this is a good solution for this case is another discussion where Rajaprabhu Aravindasam has some good points.